# Have a Composite key in M:N assosciation Using Composite Key rather having Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am creating a new database and I am using sequelize. I have two tables Table1, Table2 which has m:n relationship and third table Table3 which has a mapping of the other two tables and one more field `level`

```
Table A {
    id : P.K
    name 
  }

 Table 2 {
    id:P.K
    name
 }

 Table 3 {
    Table1.id,
    Table2.id,
    "level"
  }
```

when I use association belongstoMany it's creating an index of two foreign keys of other table (Table1.id , Table2.id)

```
    Table1.belongtoMany(Table2,
{
    through: {
       model :Table3,
       uninque :false
   }
}) 

    Table2.belongtoMany(Table1,
{
    through : {
       model :Table3,
       uninque :false
   }
})
```

Even though the unique flag is false it is still creating a primary index on (Table1.id, Table2.id)

My question is how can stop from creating the primary index automatically and rather create a composite index of (table1.id, table2.id, level) Thank you.

`edit :` the problem that I am facing is I need to add multiple ("TableA.id", "level" ) binding to "TableB.id" e.g.

```
Table A.id  | level | Table B.id
    1            |    1     |   10
    1            |    2     |   10   ---> not allowed
```

but because of the PK (TableA.id , TableB.id) it does not allow me to add the second record

how do I go about this one and I am facing this problem because the Sequelize ORM is creating a PK (TableA.id , TableB.id) even though I define composite key pm (TableA.id, level, TableB.id)

Most of my look ups will be based on TableA.id and level combination

Comment: Here's my advice on many:many:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: thank you Rick I've just edited the question can you please check it once again

Comment: There are a hundred products like sequelize that 'simplify' the use of MySQL.  What you have provided limits help from only those who know that ORM.  To get more helpers, you should provide the SQL that was generated.  (There are a lot more MySQL 'experts'.)

Comment: Sounds like Sequelize is screwing things up.  The optimal many:many table has _no_ `id` and has a 2-column PK.  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see the details.